# Why can't Windows 7 access websites on Suse Linux in LAN?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm having some weirdness issues with my local network setup, I have a development server in the basement that hosts development sites on Apache & runs DNS as well so I can lookup all my projects as http://projectX.nexus.local  and it has worked fine literally for 10 years. NOW - I have just bought a new laptop with Windows 7 & it can't find any of the sites in the `nexus.local` domain. everything else on the Internet is fine... just the local stuff gives the `site not found error [DNS]`

My `ipconfig /all` shows the correct nameservers in the correct order

```
192.168.1.99
207.164.234.193
207.164.234.129
```

`named` is running and answers queries correctly, my `resolv.conf`

```
search nexus.local
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.99
nameserver 207.164.234.193
nameserver 207.164.234.129
```

Kinda scratching my head here as my desktop can find and navigate all the local sites, but the laptop cannot. Both get their info from the same DHCP server and both have the same network information (gateway/dns etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Remove the external DNS servers from your clients and from your DHCP scope. They should only be using the internal DNS server for name resolution. This isn't strictly required in your setup but it's going to make name resolution function a whole lot better. Configure your DNS server to use the external servers as forwarders.
2. Set the connection specific DNS suffix on the laptop to match your internal DNS zone name.

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: This does make sense... I always used the external nameservers "just in case" will give it a shot.

Comment: It sure did. what was the issue here - I thought that the client machine queried the DNS servers in order, is this not the case?

Comment: It does but without a DNS suffix the DNS server doesn't know which zone (domain) to find the record in. In your case the client (without a DNS suffix or DNS suffix search list) sends a single label name query to the DNS server, which can't respond because it doesn't know which zone to look in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have nexus.local in the Windows machine's domain suffix list?